# Get Tax rates individualy in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I Have two tax rates defined

Tax Identifier    Counry  state  postcode rate

Can-QC-PS        Canada   QC     *   9.975

Can-QC-GST   Canada   QC     *   5.00

$this->item('tax_percent') will result 14.975
But i want to display individually 9.975% and 5% in the front end

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can we get current customer cart? or information such as:**

discount amount
shipping amount
tax amount
grandtotal
subtotal

it's very easy to get this values from

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()
```

**just pase this lines in your code:**

```
print_r(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getData());        // order data
print_r(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData()) // shipping data
```

And you will see what variables are available through arrays data, example:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 202933
    [store_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2011-02-25 07:22:48
    [updated_at] => 2011-02-25 13:52:34
    [converted_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [is_active] => 1
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [is_multi_shipping] => 0
    [items_count] => 1
    [items_qty] => 1
    [orig_order_id] => 0
    [store_to_base_rate] => 1
    [store_to_quote_rate] => 1
    [base_to_global_rate] => 1
    [base_to_quote_rate] => 1
    [global_currency_code] => USD
    [base_currency_code] => USD
    [store_currency_code] => USD
    [quote_currency_code] => USD
    [grand_total] => 150.71
    [base_grand_total] => 150.70636363636
    [checkout_method] => 
    [customer_id] => 
    [customer_tax_class_id] => 3
    [customer_group_id] => 0
    [customer_email] => 
    [customer_prefix] => 
    [customer_firstname] => 
    [customer_middlename] => 
    [customer_lastname] => 
    [customer_suffix] => 
    [customer_dob] => 
    [customer_note] => 
    [customer_note_notify] => 1
    [customer_is_guest] => 0
    [customer_taxvat] => 
    [remote_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [applied_rule_ids] => 
    [reserved_order_id] => 
    [password_hash] => 
    [coupon_code] => 
    [subtotal] => 117.47
    [base_subtotal] => 117.47
    [subtotal_with_discount] => 117.47
    [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 117.47
    [gift_message_id] => 
    [is_changed] => 1
    [trigger_recollect] => 0
    [ext_shipping_info] => 
    [customer_gender] => 
    [x_forwarded_for] => 
    [virtual_items_qty] => 0
    [totals_collected_flag] => 1
    [messages] => Array
        (
        )

    [all_items_qty] => 1
)
Array
(
    [address_id] => 486651
    [quote_id] => 202933
    [created_at] => 2011-02-25 07:22:50
    [updated_at] => 2011-02-25 13:52:34
    [customer_id] => 
    [save_in_address_book] => 0
    [customer_address_id] => 
    [address_type] => shipping
    [email] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [firstname] => 
    [middlename] => 
    [lastname] => 
    [suffix] => 
    [company] => 
    [street] => 
    [city] => 
    [region] => 
    [region_id] => 
    [postcode] => 
    [country_id] => US
    [telephone] => 
    [fax] => 
    [same_as_billing] => 1
    [free_shipping] => 0
    [collect_shipping_rates] => 
    [shipping_method] => owebiashipping1_code_auto018
    [shipping_description] => Expedited Shipping 3-6 days - (0.51kg) -
    [weight] => 0.51
    [subtotal] => 117.47
    [base_subtotal] => 117.47
    [subtotal_with_discount] => 0.0000
    [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 0.0000
    [tax_amount] => 0
    [base_tax_amount] => 0
    [shipping_amount] => 33.24
    [base_shipping_amount] => 33.236363636364
    [shipping_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0
    [discount_amount] => 0
    [base_discount_amount] => 0
    [grand_total] => 150.71
    [base_grand_total] => 150.70636363636
    [customer_notes] => 
    [applied_taxes] => a:0:{}
    [gift_message_id] => 
    [hidden_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_hidden_tax_amount] => 0
    [shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0
    [shipping_incl_tax] => 33.24
    [base_shipping_incl_tax] => 33.236363636364
    [discount_description] => 
    [shipping_discount_amount] => 0
    [base_shipping_discount_amount] => 0
    [subtotal_incl_tax] => 117.47
    [base_subtotal_total_incl_tax] => 
    [recurring_initial_fee_amount] => 0
    [base_recurring_initial_fee_amount] => 0
    [recurring_trial_payment_amount] => 0
    [base_recurring_trial_payment_amount] => 0
    [nominal_subtotal_amount] => 0
    [base_nominal_subtotal_amount] => 0
    [total_qty] => 1
    [base_virtual_amount] => 0
    [virtual_amount] => 0
    [base_subtotal_incl_tax] => 117.47
    [nominal_discount_amount] => 0
    [base_nominal_discount_amount] => 0
    [nominal_weee_amount] => 0
    [base_nominal_weee_amount] => 0
    [nominal_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_nominal_tax_amount] => 0
    [freeshipping_amount] => 0
    [base_freeshipping_amount] => 0
    [region_code] => 
    [rounding_deltas] => Array
        (
        )

    [free_method_weight] => 0.51
    [item_qty] => 1
    [tax_shipping_amount] => 0
    [base_tax_shipping_amount] => 0
    [shipping_taxable] => 33.24
    [base_shipping_taxable] => 33.236363636364
    [is_shipping_incl_tax] => 
    [weee_amount] => 0
    [base_weee_amount] => 0
    [applied_taxes_reset] => 1
    [applied_rule_ids] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will start to enables the "Display Full Tax Summary" option in the admin panel
System/configuration and then in the Sales/Tax/Shop display Settings
set to Yes the option "Display Full Tax Summary"

Then take a look in the cart frontend that will show both tax lines

I'will begin my investigation from the totals display

regards